# How to fetch Referrer URL's Title

Tags: javascript, url, referrer, page-title

How do we get the title of referrer URL page? I can get the referrer by

var referrer = document.referrer;

but unfortunately there's no (document.referrer).title available in javascript similar to document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML.

Any ideas how I can get this value?

Comment: can you use php / jquery?

Answer (score 0):

If any information about the referer is passed to JavaScript then it will be nothing more than the URL.

To get the title of the page you will need to [make an HTTP request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) to it and parse it out of the HTML.

If you make this HTTP request from JavaScript then it will be subject to the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)  (with the [usual work-arounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) applying).